# Why 0 is used as nullpointer in compiler headers?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When I compile my code with `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` flag i get warning like this:

```
/usr/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.0/ext/new_allocator.h:99:45: warning: zero as null pointer constant
```

pointing to :

```
      pointer
      allocate(size_type __n, const void* = static_cast<const void*>(0))
      {
```

I use c++11 or newer. Why compiler headers are written on way that rise warnings? Is `static_cast<const void*>(0)` any better than `nullptr` in this usage?

Comment: Compiler need to support pre-C++11 code.

Comment: This question requires a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is a GCC system header, and GCC suppresses warnings in system headers unless `-Wsystem-headers` is also used. If you weren't using that option, you may have found a bug where a system header warning is not suppressed as it should be, but in that case, some other part of your code will be what's triggering that bug.

Comment: @hvd Thanks! I was overeager when trying to turn on all warnings and I used `-Wsystem-headers`. It was dormant until I included a lib.
That closes case for me.